# Vuex - Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers with getters

Tags: vue.js, vuex

/pages/index.vue

```
computed: {
    escapeValues() { return this.$store.state.escapeOnline.splice(0, 1); }
}
```

/store/index.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  escapeOnline: [{id: 1, name: 'titi'}, {id: 2, 'toto'}],
})
```

When I try to run my /pages/index.vue, I can't keep the first element of my array.
And I have this error : `[vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.`

Comment: `splice` mutates the array on which it operates.
That is why you get this error.
Try using `slice` or a method which does not mutate the original array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change your state you must to use a mutation.

If you want only get first element, you can use spread operator or the method slice.

See the following example:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    escapeOnline: [{ id: '1' }, { id: '2' }, { id: '3' }, { id: '4' }, { id: '5' }, { id: '6' }],
  },
  mutations: {
    removeFirst(state) {
      state.escapeOnline.splice(0, 1);
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      {{ $store.state.escapeOnline }}
    </div>
    <div>
      <button @click="showFirst">Show First in console.log</button>
      <button @click="removeFirst">Remove First</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  methods: {
    removeFirst() {
      this.$store.commit('removeFirst');
    },
    showFirst() {
      let [first] = this.$store.state.escapeOnline;
      console.log(first);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```